# Firebase Storage 403

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm using IONIC V3 for my development with native camera plugin and Firebase for Auth, database, storage and Cloud functions [full package].

I am able to take a photo then I convert it to a BLOB then push it to Firebase Storage.

```
    this.fp.makeFileIntoBlob(imageData, "random.jpg").then((blob) => {
    this.fp.uploadToFirebase(blob,this.user.$key+'/random.jpg').then((imageUrl) => { 
           //SAVE imageUrl to Database 
      });
    });

    uploadToFirebase(_imageBlob, fileName) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var fileRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(fileName)
          fileRef.put(_imageBlob).then(function(result){
            fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(result){
              resolve(result);
            })
          });    
    });
  }
```

I receive the returned imageUrl but when I try to access it I get:
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"

TWIST: This error does not happen all the time.

Comment: I think the error come when you did not login or your user did not pass the rule in Firebase Storage

Comment: This error is because storage permissions are not satisfied i mean the storage rules only allow read and write if the user is logged in.